# Consistent cutting of pencils

Tags: cutting, square

I'm trying to cut some coloured pencils into small chunks or slices, less than 8mm I'm getting good square cuts when the stars align but the key is consistency. 
My small rotary cutting tool is fixed with a 60mm cutoff disc. The issue is throughput too. I've tried using a 32tpi blade on a hacksaw, but the friction can cause colour bleed (coloured "lead" is waxy in nature) and it just takes too long. Over 100 pieces would be a conservative estimate of number required, not too mention the variety of colours, so may need closer to 1000. 
Are there any sort of guides I can use to push a row of pencils squarely through the cutting disc? 
If I strap them together, I can obviously push them off at an angle. The answer might be to live with it and sand them as and when they are glues together in patters, but I'll take Amy suggestions at the moment.

Comment: Are you using a table saw?  It sounds like that's what you're describing, but you just call it a "cutting tool"...  By "disc" do you mean "blade"?  Or are you using a grinder or something?

Comment: Also, what exactly is the cause of your inaccuracy?  Pencils are generally manufactured fairly straight and the width shouldn't vary that much.  Are the ferrules still on?  Because I could see them messing with the stack as a whole.  Maybe do a rough cut to get them off and then restack the whole thing more tightly?

Comment: It's a rotary tool as other saws are causing the colours to "bleed". I need a method to push them through bunched together so they're all square or in a row so the first and last are still square and not at an angle

Comment: If you need to use an abrasive cutoff disc accurately maybe you should get a chop saw?  Be careful using flammable materials on a metal-cutting tool, though...  Also, I still don't understand what the source of your inaccuracy is.  Are the individual shafts not uniform or is it a workholding issue?

Comment: Yes, it's a work holding issue. The tool is fixed in a vice, but the pencils are not guided and the vice doesn't have a straight edge. I didn't know if there were guides on the market for this sort of application.

Comment: This has to be a jigged operation for consistency. Even a simple stop to butt the pencils against in effect makes a jig of sorts. We need more details of your setup to be able to advise on building a jig. A photo ideally.

Comment: How many are you doing BTW? If you're only doing a bunch now (say up to 100) without any ongoing need to cut pencils again and again I'd be tempted to just saw them by hand with a fine-toothed saw and a mitre box. And I mean literally one at a time. This might sound ridiculously slow but you'd be halfway done in the time it took to log on to SE and post the Question.

Comment: I've tried it by hand and the consistency is way off. Also, it could be three in a line, eight taped together side by side or three in a triangle. I take the point about a mitre box though.  However, maybe a rougher cut doesn't matter and they can all be sanded afterwards.  Even sanding too hard can cause colour bleed though.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to saw that way (add it to the Question) as it may help inform Answers. I just assumed you weren't doing them one at a time for speed reasons but it appears to be something different.

Comment: Get yourself a mitre box style jig and use a fine stiff blade.

Comment: @Graphus you wouldn't believe how long it can take and the wastage if it's not done right through chipping, excess bits, hard to remove colour bleed.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to add this as another Comment but I figure it is actually an Answer since you've asked for suggestions.

If I were doing this I'd be using a Japanese-style pull saw with fairly fine teeth<sup>1</sup>, and a mitre box and with a stop clamped in place to ensure consistency. Each cut would take 1-2 strokes, literally about a second per pencil<sup>2</sup>. Triple that to account for the Law of Estimates™ and it still comes to only 50 minutes.

Factor in setup time, fiddling, occasional fumbles, moments when you stare off into space trying to remember why you're doing this :-) and I figure a full thousand would easily be tackled in one afternoon. Or 2-3 lunchtimes (it would be mindlessly repetitive and boring work, so good to spread it out).

---

<sup>1</sup> A traditional dozuki would be a good choice but one of the saws from Shark would likely also work well and they'd probably be slightly cheaper. You want something in the range of 15-20 TPI.

<sup>2</sup> Pencils are usually made from what we've come to call *pencil cedar*. It's not a hard wood and saws easily if you use a saw made to cut wood.

Comment: The Law of Estimates™ — everything takes three times longer than you think it will.

Comment: 15-20tpi is suggested, but what about more? I will authenticate the answer once I've tried this out. Good info on the type of wood!

Comment: No, more is not necessary better in this case. Smaller teeth cut slower, that's arguably the most important aspect. Now they do tend to leave a better cut surface, but the sawn face left by e.g. a 17 TPI Japanese-style saw is already super nice (almost polished, if a bit wavy or rippled). One other thing that may or may not be a factor is that the gullets (the gaps between the teeth) will be more prone to clogging the higher the tooth count. So I think 15-20 is the sweet spot for cutting efficiency and good, clean cuts.

Comment: Well I used a razor pull saw at 24 tpi and unfortunately,  it didn't cut as cleanly as the rotary tool (and I can use a standard saw quite well).

Comment: You've missed the final *critical* clause from The Law of Estimates:  "... even if you have allowed for The Law of Estimates"

Comment: @MartinBonner, :-)